# french: Add \usepackage{fontspec} to the preamble of your document

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, babel, french

Consider the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french,main=american]{babel}
% \usepackage{fontspec}%%% Doesn't matter where you use fontspec
\begin{document}
Nothing.
\end{document}
```

No matter which of the two lines including the fontspec package is enabled, the warning

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: Add \usepackage{fontspec} to the 
(frenchb.ldf)                preamble of your document, on input line 5.
```

is printed to the log when compiling with xelatex or lualatex.

The output file seems to be ok. Is the warning bogus?

Versions:

- XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)
- LuaTeX Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
- LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
- Babel 2016/04/23 3.9r
- Fontspec 2017/01/24 v2.5d

Comment: Make a bug report to the french.ldf maintainer. He should adapt the code to the newest fontspec version (which no longer loads xunicode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a consequence of the recent changes in `fontspec` that stopped loading `xunicode` by default. The relevant code in `frenchb.ldf` is

```
\ifFBunicode
   \ifdefined\DeclareUTFcharacter
   \else
      \@ifpackageloaded{luainputenc}{}%
        {\PackageWarning{frenchb.ldf}%
         {Add \protect\usepackage{fontspec} to the\MessageBreak
         preamble of your document,}%
        }%
   \fi
\else
  [...irrelevant part...]
\fi
```

The `\ifBunicode` conditional is true when the engine used is either XeTeX or LuaTeX; in this case nothing is done if `\DeclareUTFcharacter` is defined, assuming this means `fontspec` has been loaded. This is the wrong test to do, because it just checks whether `xunicode` is loaded, not `fontspec`. Since this package doesn't load it any longer, the test returns false, so the warning is issued, because you aren't loading `luainputenc`, of course.

You can use the `silence` package to get rid of this spurious warning until `babel-french` is updated to look for, say, `\setmainfont`.

---

### Update

With `babel-french` version 3.2g, released 2017/01/30, the problem should be fixed. In the notes of the `.dtx` file we see

```
\changes{v3.2g}{2017/01/24}{fontspec defines TU encoding now and
  no longer loads xunicode.sty. Test changed.}
```

that shows the maintainers were already aware of the issue. Now the test is

```
\ifFBunicode
  \@ifpackageloaded{fontspec}{}%
     {\@ifpackageloaded{luainputenc}{}%
         {\PackageWarning{frenchb.ldf}%
             {Add \protect\usepackage{fontspec} to the\MessageBreak
              preamble of your document, reported}%
         }%
     }
\else
[...irrelevant part...]
\fi
```

so the loading of `fontspec` is checked specifically.

However, this doesn't allow (as it was before) to load `fontspec` after `babel`.